# Multiple Micro batch Storm Topology

Tags: apache-storm

First of all sincere apologies if my question is duplicate, I tried searching but couldn’t find relevant answer to my question

First of all sincere apologies, if i asking something very basic , as I am a beginner in Storm.
And also if my question is duplicate, As i tried searching but couldn’t find relevant answer to my question

Please advise on my below use case.

My USE Case :

I have a Spout reading data from one internal messaging mechanism, as its receiving & emitting tuples with very high frequency(100s/second).

Now every apart from data, every tuple also has a frequency(int) (as there can be total 4-5 type of frequency).

Now I need to design a Bolt to batch/Pool all tuples and only emit periodically on frequency, with a feature of emitting only latest tuple (in case of duplicate received before next batch), as we have a string-based key in tuple data to identify a duplicate.

e.g.

1. So all tuple with 25 seconds as frequency will be pooled together and will be emitted by Bolt on every 25 seconds (in case of duplicate tuple received within 25 seconds only latest one will be considered).
2. Similar like all tuple with 10 minutes as frequency will be pooled together and will be emitted by Bolt on every 10 min interval (in case of duplicate tuple received within 10 min only latest one will be considered).

** Now since we can have a 4-5 type of frequencies (e.g. 10 sec, 25 sec, 10 min, 20 min etc. , these are as configured), and every tuple should be clubbed into an appropriate batch and emitted (as exampled above).

Fyi. For Bolt grouping, I have used "fieldsGrouping" as below configuration.

```
*.fieldsGrouping("FILTERING_BOLT",new Fields(PUBLISHING_FREQUENCY));*
```

Please help or advise on,  what's the best approach for my use case, as just couldn't think of implementing anything to handle flowing of concurrent tuples and managing Storm's internal parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want windowing bolts https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Windowing.html. Probably you want a tumbling window (i.e. no overlap between window intervals)

Windowing bolts let you set an interval they should emit windows at (e.g. every 10 seconds), and then the bolt will buffer up all tuples it receives for the previous 10 seconds before calling an execute method you supply.

The structure I think you want is something like e.g.

```
spout -> splitter -> 5 second window bolt
                  -> 10 second window bolt
```

The splitter should receive the tuples, examine the frequency field and send the tuple on to the right window bolt. You make it do this by declaring a stream for each frequency type.

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare("5-sec-stream", ...);
    declarer.declare("10-sec-stream", ...);
}

public void execute(Tuple input) {
    if (frequencyIsFive(input)) {
        collector.emit("5-sec-stream", new Values(input.getValues()))
    }
    //more cases here
}
```

Then when declaring your topology you do

```
topologyBuilder.setBolt("splitter", new SplitterBolt())
     .shuffleGrouping("spout")

topologyBuilder.setBolt("5-second-window", new YourWindowingBolt())
     .globalGrouping("splitter", "5-sec-stream")
```

to make all the 5 second tuples go to the 5 second windowing bolt.

See https://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Concepts.html for more information on this, particularly the parts about streams and groupings.

There's a simple example of a windowing topology at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/SlidingWindowTopology.java.

One thing you may want to be aware of is Storm's tuple timeout. If you need a window of e.g. 10 minutes, you need to bump the tuple timeout significantly from the default of 30 seconds, so the tuples don't time out while waiting in queue. You can do this by setting e.g. `conf.setMessageTimeoutSecs(15*60)` when configuring your topology. You want there to be a bit of leeway between the window intervals and the tuple timeout, because you want to avoid your tuples timing out as much as possible.